# Language translation tool

Tags: macos, translation

Does anyone know how I can take an entire PDF and translate it from German to English.  I understand that is it not going to be perfect but it will be a start.

I am looking for one that keeps the formatting?

Comment: Stick it on the web and let Google index it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/translate-pdf-word-documents-online-google-translate/3553/

Answer (score 1):

If you can copy/paste it, [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a recent change: [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/)  can now be used to translate PDF files and Microsoft Office documents. Google first converts the document to the HTML format and then it displays the translated HTML file.

The nice thing is that Google converts the documents on the fly even if they haven't been indexed by Google. Just paste the address of a document in Google Translate's textarea and wait until the translation shows up. Unfortunately, the service is not well-suited for long documents: it only translated the first 9 pages of a PDF file.

Hope this was helpfull, if not:

- [How to Translate PDF & Word Documents with Google Translation](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/translate-pdf-word-documents-online-google-translate/3553/)
- [Translate PDF files and Office documents with Google!](http://www.googletutor.com/translate-pdf-files-and-office-documents-with-google/)